# PHP abstract class does not affect the child of its child

Tags: php, class, parent, abstract

I have an abstract class that declares the methods required to its children. It also has a construstor that its children inherits. How can I make the abstract class affect the children of the classes that extends it. To further clarify my question, here is my case:

### The Abstract Class (abstract.php):

```
<?php
include_once 'database.php';
include_once 'validation.php';

abstract class DataOperations extends DatabaseConnection {
  //The error string shared by all children of DataOperations
  //This will be the message to be displayed in case validation failure
  public $validator;
  public $err_valid_string;
  /**
  * The DataOperations' constructor ensures that all of its children can perform database operation
  * by automatically starting it for them. In case a child overrides this constructor, this child
  * must explicitly start the connection to prevent fatal errors. Also, $validator must be re-instantiated
  */
  public function __construct() {
    $this->startDBConnection();
    $this->validator = new InputValidator();
  }
  public function __destruct() {
  }

  abstract public function validateData();
  abstract public function loadRecord($key, $cascade);
  abstract public function saveRecord();
  abstract public function updateRecord();
  abstract public function deleteRecord();
}
?>
```

Now, here is the child object that extends the DataOperations abstract class

```
class Guest extends DataOperations {
  //some properties here

  public function validateData() {
    //implementation
  }

  public function newRecord(implementation) {
    //implementation
  }

  public function loadRecord($key, $cascade){
    //implementation
  }

  public function saveRecord() {
    //implementation
  }

  public function updateRecord() {
    //implementation
  }

  public function deleteRecord() {
    //implementation
  }
}
?>
```

And here is another class, which is a child of Guest

```
class Booking extends Guest {
  //some properties here

  public function validateData() {
    //implementation
  }

  public function newRecord(implementation) {
    //implementation
  }

  public function loadRecord($key, $cascade){
    //implementation
  }

  public function saveRecord() {
    //implementation
  }

  public function updateRecord() {
    //implementation
  }

  public function deleteRecord() {
    //implementation
  }
}
?>
```

The problem is, if I remove a method in Booking, say deleteRecord(), PHP won't throw an error because I think abstract class doesn't affect its 'grandchildren'. How can I fix this? I thought of using interfaces but my system already has 11 classes that depends to some methods of the abstract class. It will require intensive refactoring.

Comment: If you remove `deleteRecord` in `Booking` it will be inherited from `Guest`, so the condition of implementing `deleteRecord` is met. Depending no your situation you may want to make Guest an abstract class. But an Interface probably is the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you himself stated interface is best suited solution. Like

```
include_once 'database.php';
include_once 'validation.php';

interface DbInterface {
  abstract public function validateData();
  abstract public function loadRecord($key, $cascade);
  abstract public function saveRecord();
  abstract public function updateRecord();
  abstract public function deleteRecord();
}

class DataOperations extends DatabaseConnection {
  //The error string shared by all children of DataOperations
  //This will be the message to be displayed in case validation failure
  public $validator;
  public $err_valid_string;
  /**
  * The DataOperations' constructor ensures that all of its children can perform database operation
  * by automatically starting it for them. In case a child overrides this constructor, this child
  * must explicitly start the connection to prevent fatal errors. Also, $validator must be re-instantiated
  */
  public function __construct() {
    $this->startDBConnection();
    $this->validator = new InputValidator();
  }
  public function __destruct() {
  }

}

class Guest extends DataOperations implements DbInterface {
    - - -
}

class Booking extends Guest implements DbInterface {
    - - -
}
```

First as you see I removed abstract from parent class as I assuming only those methods are abstract. Second as per your problem of 11 classes depend on Abstract class, I would say As you only remove abstract methods, Class implementing abstract methods now should implement interface. It is one time needed task. While classes using other normal methods of abstract class work like previous.

Comment: I think I was just being paranoid when I said it will be an intensive refactoring coz my boss wanted result on the end of the day. I am now using an interface called DataOperations for all the 11 classes that connects to DatabaseConnection through a class called Backbone(silly name). It didn't require much work because I retained the methods of old DataOperations and put it to Backbone. Tnx

Comment: So to be clear, am I right when I said an abstract class's "abstract-ness" cannot affect its grandchildren?

Comment: Actually abstract methods of GrantParent abstract class (Let A) must have implemented in child classes (Let B) or child classes itself must defined as abstract. Now GrandChild Class (Let C) which extends child B of GrantParent A already have implemented methods as its parent B already implemented those methods. Once B not implementing those methods. GrantChild C have same restriction of implementing those methods.

Answer (score 0):

The best and cleanest way would be to have your "BOOKING" class extend the "DATAOPERATIONS" class, instead of GUEST, because looks like you don't have any extra methods in the BOOKING class. other wise make and interface and implement it. That is not the preferred way but you would have to give more info your situation.

Comment: Yeah i did consider what you said, but there are operations of Guest that is alike of Booking and they also have like properties and the fact that when you "book" on a hotel, you are likely to be a "guest" soon..anyway, tnx for the help

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, re-declaring a method in a child class will overwrite the parent class's implementation of that method when called from the child class, while not affecting any additional functionality provided by extending the parent class:

```
class a 
{
    function hello()
    {
        echo "Hello";
    }

    function goodbye()
    {
        echo "Goodbye";
    }
}

/**
 * class b overwrites class a's implementation of method goodbye but will retain
 * it's definition for method hello
 */
class b extends a
{
    function goodbye()
    {
        echo "See ya!";
    }
}

$object = new b();
$object->hello();  // Hello
$object->goodbye();// See ya!
```

It appears that you want to implement a consistent interface across multiple class definitions. If this is the case, you will likely want to explore using PHP's interfaces.

These allow you to specify the methods that must exist in your class definition along with their set of arguments (collectively known as the signature). Your class definitions will `implement` an interface and if your definition does not meet the interface implementation specification, a fatal error will be thrown.

From the PHP manual:

```
// Declare the interface 'iTemplate'
interface iTemplate
{
    public function setVariable($name, $var);
    public function getHtml($template);
}

// Implement the interface
// This will work
class Template implements iTemplate
{
    private $vars = array();

    public function setVariable($name, $var)
    {
        $this->vars[$name] = $var;
    }

    public function getHtml($template)
    {
        foreach($this->vars as $name => $value) {
        $template = str_replace('{' . $name . '}', $value, $template);
    }

    return $template;
}


// This will not work
// Fatal error: Class BadTemplate contains 1 abstract methods
// and must therefore be declared abstract (iTemplate::getHtml)
class BadTemplate implements iTemplate
{
    private $vars = array();

    public function setVariable($name, $var)
    {
        $this->vars[$name] = $var;
    }
}
```

You can find more information about interface in the PHP manual:

https://www.php.net/interface

Finally, it looks like you are hoping to define a common constructor for the child classes. Your child classes can both extend the DataOperations class while implementing a separate interface:

```
class Guest extends DataOperations implements DatabaseWriter
...
```